# Send Curl from objective-c Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, curl

How can I send cURL with Xcode ?

this is the Shell  code send to REST Api Server.
Convert shell to objective-c code

```
curl --include \
     --request POST \
     --header "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
     --header "Authorization: Basic NGEwMGZmMjItY2NkNy0xMWUzLTk5ZDUtMDAwYzI5NDBlNjJj" \
     --data-binary "{\"app_id\": \"5eb5a37e-b458-11e3-ac11-000c2940e62c\",
\"contents\": {\"en\": \"English Message\"},
\"included_segments\": [\"Active Users\"]}" \
     https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications
```

what is wrong here ?
The jsonData input is the problem for me

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications"];
        NSMutableURLRequest *rq = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [rq setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

        NSData *jsonData = [@"{\"app_id\": \"5eb5a37e-b458-11e3-ac11-000c2940e62c\",
\"contents\": {\"en\": \"English Message\"},
\"included_segments\": [\"Active Users\"]}" \" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        [rq setHTTPBody:jsonData];

        [rq setValue:@"application/json; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [rq setValue:@"Basic O645372ZjItM2NiOC00ZjQ2LTk4Y2UtYjFlMjE5ODBiYzg2" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
        [rq setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[jsonData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

        [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:rq completion:^(NSURLResponse *rsp, NSData *data, NSError *err) {
            NSLog(@"POST sent!");
        }];
```

It is also possible to include an NSString in the message ( NSDictionary )

```
NSString *message = @"Test Message 123";

NSDictionary *postBody =  @{
                              @"app_id":@"5eb5a37e-b458-11e3-ac11-000c2940e62c",
                              @"contents": @{@"en":@"%@", message},
                              @"included_segments": @[@"All"]
                            };
```

Comment: It doesn't look like your question has anything to do with iOS or Objective-C to start with without more information.  Besides, you probably don't want to send cURL anywhere.

Comment: So what's your error message? Did you configure the App Transport Security values in your Info.plist before trying to connect?

Comment: hello , the app configure is ok, my problem is the Json sting in the code ( jsonData )

Comment: "my problem is the Json sting in the code (`jsonData` " - you can't just put a new line in a string constant, try using an `\n` to include a newline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer is

```
NSDictionary *postBody =  @{
                              @"app_id":@"5eb5a37e-b458-11e3-ac11-000c2940e62c",
                              @"contents": @{@"en":@"English Message"},
                              @"included_segments": @[@"All"]
                            };

NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:postBody options:0 error:nil];
NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications"]];
//create the Method "POST"
[urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[urlRequest setValue:@"application/json;charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
[urlRequest setValue:@"Basic O645372ZjItM2NiOC00ZjQ2LTk4Y2UtYjFlMjE5ODBiYzg2" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
NSURLSessionUploadTask *dataTask = [session uploadTaskWithRequest: urlRequest
                                                             fromData:data completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                                                 if(data == nil && error){
                                                                     NSLog(@"uploadTaskWithRequest error: %@", error);
                                                                 }
                                                                 else{
                                                                     id jsonResp = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
                                                                     if([jsonResp isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]){
                                                                         NSDictionary *dictRes = [jsonResp copy];
                                                                         NSLog(@"The dictRes is - %@",dictRes);
                                                                     }
                                                                     else{
                                                                         NSArray *arrRes = [jsonResp copy];
                                                                         NSLog(@"The dictRes is - %@",arrRes);
                                                                     }
                                                                 }
                                                             }];
[dataTask resume];
```

I got it from [Create notification - Sends notifications to your users](https://documentation.onesignal.com/v3.0/reference)
 also from [One Signal](https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Cordova-SDK/issues/203)

Answer (score 0):

Look up the docs for NSURLSession (URLSession if you're using Swift)—it's a good starting point if you're looking to do networking on iOS.